# How to conditionally define a global variable in Ansible (AAP) workflow for all Playbooks

Tags: ansible

For an Ansible/AAP Workflow that calls many Playbooks, what are some methods for **conditionally** assigning a global variable that can be used in all subsequently called Playbooks?  Each Playbook processes a few hosts.  I want to **conditionally** assign the global variable in the first Playbook such that all subsequent Playbooks can reference this assignment.

---

Moved from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267286/how-to-conditionally-define-a-global-variable-in-ansible-aap-workflow-for-all/76267992?noredirect=1#comment134521117_76267992)

```yaml
global_dict:
  x: '{{ hostB }}'
  default: '{{ hostA }}'

ftdHost: "{{ global_dict[StandaloneFTDans=='yes'|d('default')] }}"
```

Assuming that the condition is true, ftdHost becomes the value of *x* which is set to the value of Survey variable hostA. Else, it's the default which is set to the value of Survey variable hostB.

---

Answer (score 1):

Put the global variables into the [*group_vars/all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). Use [*set_fact*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#ansible-builtin-set-fact-module-set-host-variable-s-and-fact-s) in the first playbook to create and [*cache*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) a global variable. There are more options for how to cache facts. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t cache -l
```

Let's use *jsonfile* in the example below. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t cache ansible.builtin.jsonfile
```

Create a project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── global.yml
├── hosts
├── pb1.yml
└── pb2.yml
```

Configure caching and fit other options to your needs

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
# fact_caching
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache.json
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 8640
```

Create *group_vars*. The [default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) value of *global_var* is *baz*. Set *global_condition* to select other values from *global_dict*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/global.yml 
global_dict:
  x: foo
  y: bar
  default: baz
global_var: "{{ global_dict[global_condition|d('default')] }}"
```

---

Q: ***"How the global_condition would look for a variable either 'yes' or 'no'. If SurveyAns=='yes' use variable x."***

A: Use the *group_vars* below

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/global.yml 
global_dict:
  'yes': x
  'no': y
global_var: "{{ global_dict[SurveyAns] }}"
```

and provide the variable *SurveyAns*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml -e debug=true -e SurveyAns=yes
  ...
  global_var: x
```

---

Create inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
hostA
hostB
hostC
```

Create playbooks. The first playbooks [run once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions) the module *set_fact* and cache the variable *global_var* for all hosts

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - set_fact:
            global_var: "{{ global_var }}"
            cacheable: true
        - debug:
            var: global_var
          when: debug|d(false)|bool
      run_once: true
```

For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml -e debug=true -e global_condition=x

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [hostA]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [hostA] => 
  global_var: foo

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
hostA: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Take a look at the cache files

```bash
shell> ls -1 /tmp/ansible_cache.json/
ansible_facts_hostA
ansible_facts_hostB
ansible_facts_hostC
```

The content of all cache files is the same

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_hostA
{
    "global_var": "foo"
}
```

The next playbook(s) will use the cache

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: global_var
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [hostA] => 
  global_var: foo
ok: [hostB] => 
  global_var: foo
ok: [hostC] => 
  global_var: foo

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
hostA: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostB: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostC: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

<TBD>

- Replace cache in pb1.yml
- Handle yes/no strings vs boolean

Comment: I'll have to digest this; stuff i have yet to use.  Would you please demonstrate how the global_condition would look for a Survey variable that is either 'yes' or 'no'.    That is, if SurveyAns=='yes', use variable x.

Comment: Do you really mean `variable x`? Like, for example, `SurveyAns=='no', use variable y`? Or, do you mean `value x` of, for example, a variable *global_var*.  See [mre]. Edit your question and provide (at least pseudo)code of what you want to achieve. Post the expected result.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to use an if/else statement to set a global var, however, i don't believe this construct lives in ansible/yaml.  I'll take a shot at what i'd like to work  based on your example ...
```
    global_dict:
      x: '{{ hostB}}'
      default: '{{ hostA}}'
    ftdHost: "{{ global_dict[ StandaloneFTDans=='yes'| d( 'default')] }}"
```
Assuming that the equate is true, ftdHost becomes value of X which is set to value of Survey variable hostA.  Else, it's the default which is set to value of Survey variable hostB.

Comment: Sorry about format; i tried but don't have time for it ...

Comment: No problem. I moved your code and comment to your question. Edit and improve it there when you have time. Delete the comments here.